# jquery output not working individually on php executed posts

Tags: php, jquery, html

i have a query that have many outputs and in those output i want to execute a jquery but that jquery is working in each & every output i want it to work only on the clicked one

this is my code

```
$query =  "SELECT ph.likes, ph.image_url,ph.email,ph.username,ph.uid ,ph.id,ph.avatar_path
          FROM photos as ph
          inner join followers as fol
          on fol.user_id = ph.uid
          where fol.uid = '$id'
          ORDER BY ph.image_url DESC ";
$fire = mysqli_query($con,$query) or die("can not fetch data from database ".mysqli_error($con));
if (mysqli_num_rows($fire)>0) {



  while ($users = mysqli_fetch_assoc($fire)) {
    $likes = $users['likes'];
    $username = $users['username'];
    $uid = $users['uid']; 
    $pixid = $users['id'];
    $avatar_path5 = $users['avatar_path'];


    ?>


<div class="all" >
<div class="card" >
  <div class="float" >
  <div class="avatar" >
    <img src="<?php echo $avatar_path5; ?>" width="100%" class="avatar">
  </div>

      <div class="username" style="font-weight: 600; size: 14px;  text-decoration: none;">
      <p><?php echo "<div><a href='users.php?id=".$users['uid']."'>
               <h3>".$users['username']."</h3>
      </div></a>"; ?></p>
</div>
</div>

  <img src="<?php echo $users['image_url']?>" alt="Avatar" style="width:682px;">

  <div class="container">
    <h4><b><?php echo "<div><a href='users.php?id=".$users['uid']."'>

      </div></a>";?></b></h4>

  </div>
 <span id="count" class="likes_count"><?php echo $users['likes']; ?> likes</span>
  <div style="padding: 2px; margin-top: 5px;">
  <?php
if (isset($_POST['liked'])) {
    $postid = $_POST['postid'];
    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM photos WHERE id=$postid")or die(mysqli_error($con));
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)
    or die(mysqli_error($con));
    $n = $row['likes'];

    mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO likes (user_id,username, post_id) VALUES ($id, '$fullname', $postid)")or die(mysqli_error($con));
    mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE photos SET likes=$n+1 WHERE id=$postid")or die(mysqli_error($con));

    echo $n+1;
    exit();
  }
  if (isset($_POST['unliked'])) {
    $postid = $_POST['postid'];
    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM photos WHERE id=$postid")or die(mysqli_error($con));
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)or die(mysqli_error($con));
    $n = $row['likes'];

    mysqli_query($con, "DELETE FROM likes WHERE post_id=$postid AND user_id=$id")or die(mysqli_error($con));
    mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE photos SET likes=$n-1 WHERE id=$postid")or die(mysqli_error($con));

    echo $n-1;
    exit();
  }
?>
          </div>      

      <div>

        <?php 
          // determine if user has already liked this post
           $results = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM likes WHERE user_id=$id AND post_id=".$users['id']."")or die(mysqli_error($con));

          if (mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1 ): ?>
            <!-- user already likes post -->
            <span class="unlike fas fa-heart animated bounceIn"   data-id="<?php echo $users['id']; ?>"></span> 
            <span class="like hide far fa-heart"    onclick="PlaySound()" data-id="<?php echo $users['id']; ?>"></span> 
          <?php else: ?>
            <!-- user has not yet liked post -->
            <span class="like far fa-heart"  onclick="PlaySound()" data-id="<?php echo $users['id']; ?>"></span> 
            <span class="unlike hide fas fa-heart animated bounceIn"   data-id="<?php echo $users['id']; ?>"></span> 
          <?php endif ?>
<a class="com" href="comments.php"> <span class="far fa-comment"></span></a>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>

<button class="y<?php echo $users['id']?>">Toggle slideUp() and slideDown()</button>
          <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".y").click(function(){
        $("p").slideToggle();
    });
});
</script>
        </div>
      </div><br><br>




    <?php } ?>
 see this script in my code



<p>This is a paragraph.</p>

    <button class="y<?php echo $users['id']?>">Toggle slideUp() and slideDown()</button>
              <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".y").click(function(){
            $("p").slideToggle();
        });
    });
    </script>
```

i want it to work only on the clicked post not on each & every post please help me out

for ex a if click on a post button  so i want this script to work only for  that 
particular post's button not for every post button  how to solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have the jquery selectors mixed up. From my reading of your PHP you apply a variable class name to the buttons that starts with `y`, then you select those with a class of `y` which won't match.

One way round this would be to also apply a consistent class to all the buttons (`buttonclass` in my example)

Then you're selecting all `<p>` elements to apply the `slideToggle()` instead of just the one whose button was clicked. You need to apply it only to the parent `<p>`.

This is one method of doing it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".buttonclass").click(function(){
            $(this).parent().slideToggle();
        });
    });
```